# how to pass url using segue method to web view?

Tags: ios

I am a beginner i tried in diff ways doesn't work so am looking for suggestions

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return self.objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text=self.objects[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ViewController *webview = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showdetails"])
    { // Facebook
        NSString *urlstr=@"https://www.facebook.com/";
        webview = [segue destinationViewController];
        webview.urlstr = urlstr;
        webview.title = @"Facebook"; // this sets the title of the next page                    
    }
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showdetails"]) { // Instagram
        NSString *urlstr=@"http://instagram.com/";
        webview = [segue destinationViewController];
        webview.urlstr = urlstr;
        webview.title = @"Instagram"; // this sets the title of the next page
    }
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showdetails"]) { // Twitter
        NSString *urlstr=@"https://twitter.com/";
        webview = [segue destinationViewController];
        webview.urlstr = urlstr;
        webview.title = @"Twitter"; // this sets the title of the next pag
    }
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showdetails"]) { // YouTube
        NSString *urlstr=@"http://www.youtube.com/";
        webview = [segue destinationViewController];
        webview.urlstr = urlstr;
        webview.title = @"YouTube"; // this sets the title of the next page
    }
    self.title = @"Follow"; // This sets the title of the back button, and the title of this page

}
```

Comment: whats yuour question  ...? what teh answer you expect

Comment: what s exactly u want?

Comment: Same Identifier for all segues ???????

Comment: am just new to this, so i need to know how to pass diff url's from segue to web view? can i get coding for that?

Answer (score 0):

Implement below method and pass your desire object in it.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    secondViewController *controller = (secondViewController *)navController;
    NSString *urlstr=@"https://www.facebook.com/";
    secondViewController.urlstr = urlstr;
}
```

and one thing more, don't use same Identifier for all segues.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
DestinationClassName *Object = (DestinationClassName *)segue.destinationViewController;

        NSString *yrURL=@"https://www.google.com/";
        Object.webURL = yrURL;
}
```

in DestinationClassName, get webURL string and make URL using webURL.like

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.webURL];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```